# function b64_md5(s) for C#

Tags: c#

One of my client site uses [MD5.js](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/md5.html)

in particular this function

```
function b64_md5(s)    { return rstr2b64(rstr_md5(str2rstr_utf8(s))); }
```

Is there an equivalent of this in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to return the Base64 representation of a MD5 hash of a string this would be equivalent:

```
public static string GetMD5Base64Hash(string strToHash)
{
    byte[] byteStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strToHash);
    byte[] hashVal = (new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider()).ComputeHash(byteStr);
    string base64Hash = Convert.ToBase64String(hashVal);
    return base64Hash;
}
```

Comment: What is interesting is that for any strToHash, the return puts '==' at end of string.

Comment: I mean the padding bytes. Is there a way to avoid them?

Comment: @CapsLock: technically they are not needed since you can calculate the missing bytes - I don't know if `Convert.FromBase64String` needs them to work correctly though. If you use a different decoding routine just chop them off and find out!

Comment: what i did is this 
return base64Hash.Replace("=", " ").Trim();

Not elegant and I think it may fail, but it seems to be working for now

Comment: You can use `return base64Hash.TrimEnd('=');` but the result should be the same either way since `=` is only used for padding

Answer (score 0):

[System.Security.Cryptography.MD5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5.aspx)